# Store multiple values in a file - best format?

Tags: java, file, storage

I want to store multiple values (String, Int and Date) in a file via Java in Android Studio.
I don't have that much experience in that area, so I tried to google a bit, but I didn't get the solution, which I've been looking for. So, maybe you can recommend me something?

What I've tried so far:

- Android offers a SharedPreferences feature, which allows a user to save a primitive value for a key. But I have multiple values for a key, so that won't work for me.
- Another option is saving data on an external storage medium as file. As far as good. But I want to keep the filesize at minimum and load the file as fast as possible. That's the place, where I can't get ahead. If I directly save all values as simple text, I would need to parse the .txt file per hand to load the data which will take time for multiple entries.

Is there a possibility to save multiple entries with multiple values for a particular key in an efficient way?

Comment: maybe JSON file?

Comment: Json might not be the optimal solution, sqlite or any other RDMS on the device might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to reinvent a bicycle. Most probably the best option for your case is using the databases. Look into [Sqlite](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite) or [Realm](https://realm.io/blog/realm-for-android/).

Comment: I also considered a database, but isn't a database bigger than a regular file?

Comment: I will try your recommendation and use Realm as an android database. I hope this will work out well

Answer (score 1):

You don’t divulge enough details about your data structure or volume, so it is difficult to give a specific solution.

Generally speaking, you have these three choices.

## Serialize a collection

> I have multiple values for a key

You could use a `Map` with a `List` or `Set` as its value.  This has been discussed countless times on Stack Overflow.

Then use Serialization to write and read to storage.

## Text file

Write a text file.

Use Tab-delimited or CSV format if appropriate. I suggest using the Apache Commons CSV library for that.

## Database

If you have much data, or concurrency issues with multiple threads, use a database such as the H2 Database Engine.